# Since the Refocus activity requires spending a Focus Point before I Refocus again, can I only fully replenish my focus pool by resting?

Tags: actions, pathfinder-2e, rests, focus-pool

I'm a bit unsure about how the [Refocus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=71) activity works. If I have a pool of 3 focus points and spend 2, according to the Refocus rules I can regenerate 1, but need to use up at least 1 again before I can refocus again.

Am I overlooking something, or can I only come to a full focus point pool again by resting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, yes, you can only recover 1 focus point after every use no matter how many you spent. However, you can take class feats that increase this amount. All classes with focus spells have access to an "X Focus" feat at level 10-14 that allows them to recover two points at once, and some have an additional "X Wellspring" feat at level 18 that increases it to three points (the others are always limited to two at most, unfortunately).

**Bard:** [Inspirational Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=202) (12)

**Champion:** [Devoted Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=237) (10)

**Cleric:** [Domain Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=295) (12), [Domain Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=305) (18)

**Druid:** [Primal Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=342) (12), [Primal Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=352) (18)

**Magus:** [Conflux Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2875) (12), [Conflux Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2882) (18)

**Monk:** [Meditative Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=471) (12), [Meditative Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=485) (18)

**Oracle:** Special, class feature level 11 and 17

**Psychic:** Special, class feature (level 1), [Deepest Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3693) (18)

**Ranger:** [Warden's Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1776) (12), [Warden's Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1777) (18)

**Sorcerer:** [Bloodline Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=621) (12), [Bloodline Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=628) (18)

**Summoner:** [Link Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2930)  (12), [Link Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2939) (18)

**Witch:** [Hex Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1583) (12), [Hex Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1588) (18)

**Wizard:** [Bonded Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=655) (14)

Comment: Does every class have such a line of feats, or are there some that are not as good at the Refocus activity?

Comment: @royalmurder Clerics, Druids, Monks, and Sorcerers each have feats for 2 and 3 focus point Refocusing; Bards, Champions, and Wizards have access to Focus spells but only have feats to increase their restored focus to 2.

Comment: As it differs, perhaps it may be beneficial to add such information to the answer. I think enough people will come here with similar questions that it’ll be worthwhile.

Comment: @royalmurder I've updated my answer with links to all of the feats in question.

Comment: Another way to avoid the limitation is to get a familiar.  One of the choices of Master Ability is [Familiar Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=15) (Core Rules p. 218): Once per day, your familiar can use 2 actions with the concentrate trait to restore 1 Focus Point to your focus pool, up to your usual maximum.