# How can Psychics regain 2 Focus Points?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, psychic-class, focus-pool

While adding some classes to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/164263/49393), I could not find the feat that enables the Psychic to regain 2 Focus Points (FP). While it is not unprecedented that a class cannot regain all 3 FPs<sup>1</sup>, Psychics have those ([Deepest Wellspring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3693)), but not 2.

I do not have access to the book, so this could be just a mistake on AoN, but all other Wellspring feats list the 2 FP feat as a prerequisite, unlike this one.

Is there a class feat for Psychic to regain 2 FPs?

---

1. Wizards can only get 2 FP back

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is none, because you have that ability from the start. In the section about psi cantrips and amps, in the part about the refocus activity, it says:

> If you've spent Focus Points only to amp psi cantrips or fuel psychic
> abilities since the last time you Refocused, you regain 2 Focus Points
> when you Refocus, up to your maximum of 2. If you've spent Focus
> Points on focus spells or abilities other than those from the psychic
> class (for instance, to cast a focus spell you gained from an
> archetype), you regain only 1 Focus Point.

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks